# ¿Porqué obtengo un error en mi clase?

Tags: javascript

Estoy realizando un ejercicio en el que declaro una clase `Mascota` y una función que se encarga de crearla, tal que así:

```
function crearClaseMascota()
{
    class Mascota
    {
        constructor(nombre, dueño, actividades) 
        
        this.nombre      = nombre;
        this.dueño       = dueño;
        this.actividades = actividades;
    }

    addActividad(actividad, frecuencia)
    {
        Mascota[actividades] = function( actividad, frecuencia){
        this.actividad       = actividad;
        this.frecuencia      = frecuencia;
    }

}
```

El método `addActividad` recibe una cadena de texto `actividad` y otra cadena `frecuencia`  y debe agregarlo al arreglo de actividades de la mascota. No debe retornar nada.

Sin embargo, me parece que no es la forma correcta, ya que el resultado no me da. Tal vez, al usar notación por punto o notación por corchete no estaría accediendo de la forma que debería ser.

¿Podrían ayudarme?

Comment: aqui debajo ya te dieron una respuesta detallada de como estructurar tu objeto, no te olvides de marcarla como 'util' utilizando el check.

Comment: No son notaciones diferentes. Es una sola notación en la que los paréntesis significan una cosa, las llaves otra y los corchetes otra.

Answer (score 1):

Luego de ver tu [pregunta anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/579460/169744) relacionada, y ahora esta, he notado que tienes algunas dificultades para conseguir una correcta estructura para tu clase `Mascota`. Permíteme orientarte.

Lo primero es que tu clase `Mascota` debería estar fuera de tu función `crearClaseMascota`, tal que así:

```
class Mascota
{
    ...
}

function crearClaseMascota()
{
    let mascota = new Mascota();
}
```

Porque, si indicas que una clase será creada mediante una función, por lo general suele referirse a crear [una instancia](https://es.theastrologypage.com/instantiate) de la clase, no a crear la declaración en sí.

Además, en tu contructor, se aprecian estos parámetros: `(nombre, dueño, actividades)`. Es recomendable codificar en inglés, pero, si decides hacerlo en otro lenguaje, como el español, por ejemplo, **no emplees caracteres no ingleses como la letra ñ** o letras acentuadas, ya que esto puede traer problemas diversos. Opta por algo como `dueno` o, en su defecto, `duenio`.

De esta forma:

```
class Mascota
{
    constructor(nombre, dueno, actividades) 
    {
        this.nombre        = nombre;
        this.dueno         = dueno;
        this.actividades   = actividades;
    }
}
```

Ahora, en tu método `addActividad` tienes algunos errorcillos de sintaxis simples de solventar. Por ejemplo, quieres que este método agregue una actividad a tu lista de actividades. Para ello debes emplear el método de JavaScript [`Array.prototype.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

Te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
let actividades = [ 'Correr', 'Jugar' ];

console.log('Actividades: ', actividades);

actividades.push('Bañarse', 'Pasear' /*, etc.*/);

console.log('Actividades nuevas: ', actividades);
```

Al método `push` le puedes pasar una o varias actividades (separadas por coma). Veo además que `addActividad` recibe dos parámetros, la actividad como tal y la frecuencia de dicha actividad. Entonces, permíteme proponerte el siguiente enfoque:

```js
class Mascota
{
    constructor(nombre, dueno, actividades)
    {
        this.nombre        = nombre;
        this.dueno         = dueno;
        this.actividades   = actividades;
    }
    
    addActividad(actividad, frecuencia)
    {
        this.actividades.push({ actividad, frecuencia });
    }
    
    getActividades()
    {
        return this.actividades;
    }
}

let mascota = new Mascota
(
    'Firulais',
    'Marco Pérez',
    [ { actividad: 'Correr', frecuencia: '1 vez al día' },
      { actividad: 'Jugar',  frecuencia: '3 veces al día' } ]
);

console.log('Actividades de mi mascota: ', mascota.getActividades());

mascota.addActividad('Pasear', 'Interdiario');
mascota.addActividad('Bañarse', '1 vez por mes');

console.log('Actividades nuevas de mi mascota: ', mascota.getActividades());
```

Se trata de emplear una lista de objetos, y cada objeto a su ves, contiene la actividad y la frecuencia. Esto simplifica bastante las cosas, ya que puedes colocar toda la información en una sola lista.

Y que no se olvide, por supuesto, la adición que responde a tu [pregunta anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/579460/169744):

```js
class Mascota
{
    constructor(nombre, dueno, actividades)
    {
        this.nombre        = nombre;
        this.dueno         = dueno;
        this.actividades   = actividades;
    }
    
    getNombre()
    {
        return this.nombre;
    }
    
    setNombre(nombre)
    {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    
    addActividad(actividad, frecuencia)
    {
        this.actividades.push({ actividad, frecuencia });
    }
    
    getActividades()
    {
        return this.actividades;
    }
}

let mascota = new Mascota
(
    'Firulais',
    'Marco Pérez',
    [ { actividad: 'Correr', frecuencia: '1 vez al día' },
      { actividad: 'Jugar',  frecuencia: '3 veces al día' } ]
);

console.log('Nombre de mi mascota: ', mascota.getNombre());

mascota.setNombre('Doggo');

console.log('Nuevo nombre de mi mascota: ', mascota.getNombre());
```

Donde `getNombre` devuelve el nombre que tenga tu instancia de `Mascota`, ya sea que lo hayas pasado mediante el constructor o mediante el método `setNombre` que establece (o cambia si ya estaba asignado) el nombre de dicha mascota.

---

Edito:

Si deseas que `getActividades` devuelva algo como `['Bañarse', 'Jugar']` en vez de `[{ actividad: 'Bañarse', frecuencia: '1 vez al mes' }, { actividad:'Jugar', frecuencia: '1 vez al día' }]`, puedes optar por este enfoque:

```js
class Mascota
{
    constructor(nombre, dueno, actividades)
    {
        this.nombre        = nombre;
        this.dueno         = dueno;
        this.actividades   = actividades;
    }
    
    addActividad(actividad, frecuencia)
    {
        this.actividades.push({ actividad, frecuencia });
    }
    
    getActividades()
    {
        return this.actividades.map(a => a.actividad);
    }
}

let mascota = new Mascota
(
    'Firulais',
    'Marco Pérez',
    [ { actividad: 'Correr', frecuencia: '1 vez al día' },
      { actividad: 'Jugar',  frecuencia: '3 veces al día' } ]
);

console.log('Actividades de mi mascota: ', mascota.getActividades());

mascota.addActividad('Pasear', 'Interdiario');
mascota.addActividad('Bañarse', '1 vez por mes');

console.log('Actividades nuevas de mi mascota: ', mascota.getActividades());
```